# Nesting DataTables

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset

I'd like to nest a DataTable into another DataTable, like this:

```
<Mail>
  <SMTP>
    <Server>smtp.myserver.de</Server>
      <Port>25</Port>
    <Security>STARTTLS</Security>
      <Authmethod>Login</Authmethod>
  </SMTP>
  <IMAP>
    <Server>imap.myserver.de</Server>
      <Port>993</Port>
      <Security>STARTTLS</Security>
      <Authmethod>Login</Authmethod>
  </IMAP>
  <Username>myusername</Username>
  <Password>mypassword</Password>
  <Mailaddress>me@myserver.de</Mailaddress>
</Mail>
```

My code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataTable dtsmtp = new DataTable();
DataTable dtimap = new DataTable();
dt.TableName = "Mail";
dtsmtp.TableName = "SMTP";
dtimap.TableName = "IMAP";
DataColumn dcsmtp1 = new DataColumn("Server");
DataColumn dcsmtp2 = new DataColumn("Port");
DataColumn dcsmtp3 = new DataColumn("Security");
DataColumn dcsmtp4 = new DataColumn("Authmethod");

DataColumn dcimap1 = new DataColumn("Server");
DataColumn dcimap2 = new DataColumn("Port");
DataColumn dcimap3 = new DataColumn("Security");
DataColumn dcimap4 = new DataColumn("Authmethod");

DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Username");
DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Password");
DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Mailaddress");

dtsmtp.Columns.Add(dcsmtp1);
dtsmtp.Columns.Add(dcsmtp2);
dtsmtp.Columns.Add(dcsmtp3);
dtsmtp.Columns.Add(dcsmtp4);

dtimap.Columns.Add(dcimap1);
dtimap.Columns.Add(dcimap2);
dtimap.Columns.Add(dcimap3);
dtimap.Columns.Add(dcimap4);

dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
dt.Columns.Add(dc3);

dtsmtp.Rows.Add("smtp.myserver.de", "25", "STARTTLS", "Password");
dtimap.Rows.Add("imap.myserver.de", "993", "STARTTLS", "Password");

dt.Rows.Add(dtsmtp);
dt.Rows.Add(dtimap);

dt.Rows.Add("myusername", "mypassword", "me@myserver.de");

ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

If I get it right, it will be enough to add the tables "SMTP" and "IMAP" to my main table "Mail". Unfortunately it does not work, I only get:

```
<Mail>
  <Username>SMTP</Username>
</Mail-Configuration>
<Mail-Configuration>
  <Username>IMAP</Username>
</Mail>
<Mail>
  <Username>myusername</Username>
  <Password>mypassword</Password>
  <Mailaddress>me@myserver.de</Mailaddress>
</Mail>
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please. Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**
Sorry! In the first place, I should have mentioned I use WriteXml() to get it into XML format.
After I inserted the relation I get:

```
<Mail>
  <Username>myusername</Username>
  <Password>mypassword</Password>
  <Mailaddress>me@myserver.de</Mailaddress>
  <smtp_id>Mail_SMTP</smtp_id>
  <imap_id>Mail_IMAP</imap_id>
</Mail>
<SMTP>
  <Server>smtp.myserver.de</Server>
  <Port>25</Port>
  <Security>STARTTLS</Security>
  <Authmethod>Login</Authmethod>
</SMTP>
<IMAP>
  <Server>imap.myserver.de</Server>
  <Port>993</Port>
  <Security>STARTTLS</Security>
  <Authmethod>Login</Authmethod>
</IMAP>
```

So, we're close, but not close enough...

Code:

```
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.Tables.Add(dtimap);
ds.Tables.Add(dtsmtp);

DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("Mail_SMTP", dtsmtpId, dcsmtpdtId, true);
relation.Nested = true;
ds.Relations.Add(relation);

DataRelation relation1 = new DataRelation("Mail_IMAP", dtimapid, dcimapdtId, true);
relation1.Nested = true;
ds.Relations.Add(relation1);

dt.Rows.Add("myusername", "mypassword", "me@myserver.de", relation, relation1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding all tables inside the dataset and create relationship between the tables by using unique identity column

```
//Create new unique column to maintain relationship between tables
DataColumn dtId = new DataColumn("Id"); //it act as primary key
dtId.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden; //hide mapping column while generating xml

DataColumn dcimap_dtId = new DataColumn("Mail_Id"); // foreign key
dcimap_dtId.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;

DataColumn dcsmtp_dtId = new DataColumn("Mail_Id"); // foreign key
dcsmtp_id.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;

// add newly created columns into appropriate tables and position
...
//fill data rows as per data table column arrangement
dt.Rows.Add(1, "myusername", "mypassword", "me@myserver.de"); // 1 is primary key
dtsmtp.Rows.Add("smtp.myserver.de", "25", "STARTTLS", "Password", 1); // 1 is here act as foreign key
dtimap.Rows.Add("imap.myserver.de", "993", "STARTTLS", "Password", 1);

// add all tables inside the dataset
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.Tables.Add(dtsmtp);
ds.Tables.Add(dtimap);

//create relationship between tables
DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("Mail_SMTP", dtId, dcsmtp_dtId, true);
relation.Nested = true;
ds.Relations.Add(relation);

DataRelation relation1 = new DataRelation("Mail_IMAP", dtId, dcimap_dtId, true);
relation1.Nested = true;
ds.Relations.Add(relation1);

//Write to file
ds.WriteXml("file.xml");
```

Ref: [Complete Solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qiQFV4)

--SJ

Comment: as you can see in my "Edit" above: I don't understand how to add properly the relation to my row. I tried: dt.Rows.Add("myusername", "mypassword", "me@myserver.de", relation, relation1); But writeXML() produces: <Mail>...</Mail><SMTP>...</SMTP><IMAP>...</IMAP> So, SMTP & IMAP is not nested into MAIL as expected

Comment: you don't need to add relationship object as a table columns; instead add relationship object to the dataset. see the updated code snippet it will help you how to add new rows to datatable. let me know if you still facing the problem

Comment: Hey codeninja, that's great. finally, I managed to nest SMTP & IMAP into MAIL. Unfortunately, writeXML() prints out the "relationship columns". I get: 
<Mail>
  <Username />
  <Password />
  <Mailaddress />
  <MailId>1</MailId>
  <SMTP>
    ...
    <smtp_Id>1</smtp_Id>
  </SMTP>
  <IMAP>
    ...
    <imap_Id>1</imap_Id>
  </IMAP>
</Mail>

How can I hide the "relationship columns" ?

Comment: you need to set ColumnMapping type value as hidden. see the update solution.

Answer (score 0):

If **not xml generation** is required first by the datatables then datatables should not be structured like so. They should be put into dataset and added relations. This makes sure proper organization.

For xml generation it is better to use other tools like [`XDocument` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to add `dtsmtp` and `dtimap` as rows to your `dt` datatable. To get the structure I think you're after you need to add smtp and imap **columns** to your `dt` datatable, and then add `dtsmtp` and `dtimap` when you're adding the other data...

```
dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
dt.Columns.Add("smtp", typeof(DataTable));
dt.Columns.Add("imap", typeof(DataTable));

dtsmtp.Rows.Add("smtp.myserver.de", "25", "STARTTLS", "Password");
dtimap.Rows.Add("imap.myserver.de", "993", "STARTTLS", "Password");

dt.Rows.Add("myusername", "mypassword", "me@myserver.de", dtsmtp, dtimap);
```

I'm not sure the method you're using to convert this to XML, but this is the *sort* of structure you'd want.

Comment: btw, this all seems a bit nasty. There's almost definitely a nicer way of achiving what you're after without nesting datatables.